# Codeigniter $query->result() returns strange results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This peace of code is driving me crazy for last hour...
I have this model which should return all non active records from DB

```
    $query = $this->db->get($tableName);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    var_dump($query->result());
```

`$this->db->last_query()` output is

```
SELECT * FROM `locations` LEFT JOIN `provinces` ON `provinces`.`id_province` = `locations`.`id_province` LEFT JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id_country` = `provinces`.`id_country` LEFT JOIN `statuses` ON `statuses`.`id_status` = `locations`.`id_status` WHERE `locations`.`active` = '0' ORDER BY `locations`.`id_location` DESC LIMIT 50
```

If i run exactsame query in phpmyadmin i get correct results

[image]

But when i var_dump data `var_dump($query->result());` i get the following results

```
array (size=50)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[61]
      public 'unique_id' => string 'OWYwYjBmNm' (length=10)
      public 'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'owner_name' => string 'Cleve Greenfelder' (length=17)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[62]
      public 'unique_id' => string 'YWY4YmMzMm' (length=10)
      public 'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'owner_name' => string 'Bradford Hyatt' (length=14)
```

Why/how this active state get's overwritten from 0 to 1? 
IF you need any additional information's, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Comment: Several active columns would be my guess?

Comment: yeeaaa :D after i have wrote a question i figure out that countries table also has active state :D

Comment: in var_dump active column belongs to countries table

Comment: Try $query->result_array()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once i wrote a question, answer quickly appeared in my head :)
Table Countries has also active field, so this field overwrites active state as enabled.  I needed to specified fields and there's name in query in order to get proper results

```
$fields = 'unique_id, locations.active as active, ....';
```